# Make WebTorrent handle magnet links

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I seem to have forgotten how to make WebTorrent, or any torrent application automatically grab the magnet torrent links from websites like thepiratebay.org?

There's no file to download so I cannot choose the prefered application, and it's being opened my the Ubuntu's default - Transmission.

Help?

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.instantfundas.com/2010/01/what-are-bittorrent-magnet-links-and.html) it gives an explanation on how to use uTorrent to create one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Desktop default or any tool using `xdg-open` directly (including Chrome/Chromium). To check the current default use:

  ```
  ~$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
  transmission-gtk.desktop
  ```

  To check available tools:

  ```
  ~$ grep -r -e "application/x-bittorrent" -e "x-scheme-handler/magnet" /usr/share/applications/
  /usr/share/applications/deluge.desktop:MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
  /usr/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop:MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
  /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:application/x-bittorrent=transmission-gtk.desktop;deluge.desktop;
  /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop;deluge.desktop;
  ```

  To set another tool, for example Deluge:

  ```
  xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
  ```
- Firefox lets you choose which application handles each type of link (URL):

  Firefox menu → Preferences → Applications → `magnet`: Choose Use other.

  [image: Firefox: setting magnet handler]

Comment: Need it for chrome.

Comment: @Mookey, updated my answer. Tested only with chromium.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the address (by right click) and past it (with Ctrl+V) in WebTorrent after File -> Open Torrent Address.

This is not automatic but it should work. The automation depends on the browser you are using.

You should try to see in your browser documentation for an "left-click" solution.

Comment: I know I can do that, I need it automatically connected to clicking the magnet link in Chrome.