# Magnet links are automatically opened by stremio

Tags: qbittorrent

As soon as I had installed Stremio all the magnet links are opened in Stremio instead of qbittorrent or any other torrent program.

So far I have found a way out by copying the Magnet link (right-clicking the Magnet link and copying it). I am using Chrome as the default browser. I found [some what Similar issue in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860716/make-webtorrent-handle-magnet-links). Firefox seems to not be affected and it did ask me to open which program I wanted to open but Firefox was unable to open qbittorent. Even though I had given it bqitorrent location `/usr/bin/qbittorrent`

Answer (score -1):

If Stremio is directly opening the magnet link. You can go ahead and reset the Chrome settings. It resets just the settings which should probably reset the default redirection.

To perform a reset, **Three dots > Settings > Reset Settings**

Next time when you try to open a magnet link you should receive a popup asking to open, like this:

*`somewebsite wants to open this application.`*

Click on **xdg-open** and it would list the apps, which should most likely include qBittorrent also.

All the best!

Comment: Resetting my browser means losing all my settings and passwords. Can I reset only the settings for torrents and magnets default application file associations?

Comment: What are the settings that you have adjusted? To my knowledge resetting does not delete your passwords. As the name suggests it only resets **settings**

Comment: I did as you told me but still stremio is opening the magnet links. btw: My chrome had three users; does your solution had to done on all the users. Because one user reset doesnot do it